# How can I search for a string in multiple columns and return the value in the column to the right in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

So I am working with a table that looks similar to the following:

```
ID = ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007']
substance_1 = ['Alcohol', 'Meth', 'Alcohol', 'Marijuana','Alcohol' 'Crack', 'Heroin']
substance_1_freq = ['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Daily', 'Daily', 'Daily', 'Monthly', 'Weekly']
substance_2 = ['Meth', 'Alcohol', 'Marijuana', 'Heroin', 'Crack', 'Alcohol', 'Alcohol']
substance_2_freq = ['Weekly', 'Daily', 'Daily', 'Monthly', 'Monthly', 'Daily', 'Weekly']
substance_3 = ['Crack', None, None, 'Alcohol', 'Marijuana', None, None]
substance_3_freq = ['Weekly', None, None, 'Daily', 'Daily', None, None]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ID,substance_1, substance_1_freq, substance_2, substance_2_freq, substance_3, substance_3_freq)),
                  columns = ['ID','substance_1', 'substance_1_freq', 'substance_2', 'substance_2_freq', 'substance_3', 
                             'substance_3_freq'])
```

There are multiple columns describing the drug use for each ID. If there is a drug entered into the "substance" columns, the drug frequency is entered into the column to the right. Ultimately I want to create a one-hot-encoded column for each of the drugs. I also want to create a frequency column for each drug.

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
| ID |  Alcohol | Alc_freq | Meth  | Meth_freq | Crack | Crack_freq | etc.....
| 1  |     1    | Daily    |  1    |  Weekly   |   1   |    Weekly  |
| 2  |     1    | Daily    |  1    |  Weekly   |   0   |     None   |
| 3  |     1    | Daily    |  0    |  None     |   0   |     None   |
| 4  |     1    | Daily    |  0    |  None     |   0   |     None   |
| 5  |     1    | Daily    |  0    |  None     |   1   |   Monthly  |
| 6  |     1    | Daily    |  0    |  None     |   1   |   Monthly  |
| 7  |     1    | Weekly   |  0    |  None     |   0   |     None   |
```

Any suggestions rather than writing a np.where statement for every drug and each of the 3 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your dataframe in two parts: substance and frequency then reshape them and finally concatenate to get the expected result:

```
# Split in 2 dataframes
subst = df1.filter(regex='^ID|substance_\d+$').melt('ID').dropna()
freq = df1.filter(regex='^ID|substance_\d+_freq$').melt('ID').dropna()
freq['subst'] = subst['value'] + '_freq'

# Reshape by pivoting
subst = pd.crosstab(subst['ID'], subst['value'])
freq = freq.pivot(index='ID', columns='subst', values='value')

# Concatenate & sort
out = pd.concat([subst, freq], axis=1)
out = out.iloc[:, np.argsort(out.columns.str.split('_').str[0])].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    ID  Alcohol Alcohol_freq  AlcoholCrack AlcoholCrack_freq  Crack Crack_freq  Heroin Heroin_freq  Marijuana Marijuana_freq  Meth Meth_freq
0  001        1        Daily             0               NaN      1     Weekly       0         NaN          0            NaN     1    Weekly
1  002        1        Daily             0               NaN      0        NaN       0         NaN          0            NaN     1    Weekly
2  003        1        Daily             0               NaN      0        NaN       0         NaN          1          Daily     0       NaN
3  004        1        Daily             0               NaN      0        NaN       1     Monthly          1          Daily     0       NaN
4  005        0          NaN             1             Daily      1    Monthly       0         NaN          1          Daily     0       NaN
5  006        1        Daily             0               NaN      0        NaN       1     Monthly          0            NaN     0       NaN
```

**Update**

> I keep ending with the error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

For debugging purpose, use:

```
# Split in 2 dataframes
subst = df1.filter(regex='^ID|substance_\d+$').melt('ID').dropna()
freq = df1.filter(regex='^ID|substance_\d+_freq$').melt('ID').dropna()
freq['subst'] = subst['value'] + '_freq'

# Reshape by pivoting
subst = pd.crosstab(subst['ID'], subst['value'])
freq = freq.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='subst', values='value', aggfunc=lambda x: x if len(x) == 1 else list(x))

# Concatenate & sort
out = pd.concat([subst, freq], axis=1)
out = out.iloc[:, np.argsort(out.columns.str.split('_').str[0])].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
#    You have duplicates --v
    ID  Alcohol     Alcohol_freq  AlcoholCrack AlcoholCrack_freq  Crack Crack_freq  Heroin Heroin_freq  Marijuana Marijuana_freq  Meth Meth_freq
0  001        2  [Daily, Weekly]             0               NaN      1     Weekly       0         NaN          0            NaN     0       NaN
1  002        1            Daily             0               NaN      0        NaN       0         NaN          0            NaN     1    Weekly
2  003        1            Daily             0               NaN      0        NaN       0         NaN          1          Daily     0       NaN
3  004        1            Daily             0               NaN      0        NaN       1     Monthly          1          Daily     0       NaN
4  005        0              NaN             1             Daily      1    Monthly       0         NaN          1          Daily     0       NaN
5  006        1            Daily             0               NaN      0        NaN       1     Monthly          0            NaN     0       NaN
```

Comment: This gets me really close. I keep ending with the error "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". This occurs in the freq dataframe. This is because there are up to 3 entries per ID (depending on number of substances). How did you overcome this?

Comment: How is it possible? For same ID, you can have (Alcohol, Daily) and (Alcohol, Weekly)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why it was flagging that error, was just how I interpreted it. Your code works great on the example dataframe. Not sure what the hang up is on my dataset. It happens when I try to pivot the freqs table.

Comment: Try to check the output of `subst`. Do you have some values greater than 1?

Comment: I do... I the values range from 0 to 2 for some of the substances. There are for sure no duplicates of ID though.

Comment: You just have to ensure for a same (ID, substance), you have the same frequency. If not, does it make sense?

Comment: For debugging, can you replace `freq.pivot` line by `freq = freq.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='subst', values='value', aggfunc=lambda x: x if len(x) == 1 else list(x))`

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. Yes I could pivot the table if I used freq.pivot_table with an aggfunc = 'first'.

Comment: I updated my answer. Now you can check what happens really. I slightly modified your dataframe to have duplicates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252719/discussion-between-brandooo23-and-corralien).